# In Python, Unable to retrieve "dictionary inside a list" from stdout

Tags: python-2.7

I am executing a curl command and the output is in json format like this, which i am redirecting to a outputfile

[{ "createdDateTime": "2015-03-24T12:06:45.403+0000", "Id": "123", "ToDo": "VIEW"}, { "createdDateTime": "2015-03-25T06:30:31.624+0000", "Id": "456", "ToDo": "VIEW"}]

I am trying the below code to access the Id information from this data.
I thought it is a dictionary inside a list. But python processes it in a different way. please provide your inputs.

```
import subprocess
import shlex

cmd="curl \-X GET 'xxx'"
shlex.split(cmd)
p1=subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p1.communicate()
print stdout
jsonFile = open('jsonFile.txt', 'w')
jsonFile.writelines(str(stdout))
jsonFile.close()
jsonFile = open('jsonFile.txt', 'r')
jsonout = [jsonFile.readlines()]
Ids = [d['Id'] for d in jsonout]
print Ids
```

## Output:

[['[{ "createdDateTime": "2015-03-24T12:06:45.403+0000", "Id": "123", "ToDo": "VIEW"}, { "createdDateTime": "2015-03-25T06:30:31.624+0000", "Id": "456", "ToDo": "VIEW"}]']]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 16, in 
    Ids = [d['Id'] for d in jsonout]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: Considered using a json parser library? Such as this one: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Answer (score 0):

Python has an comprehensive [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module to deal with tasks like that.

```
import json
with open ('jsonFile.txt', 'r') as f:
    jsonout = json.load(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're not using a json parser library. Try this instead:

```
import json
jsonout=json.loads(open('jsonFile.txt', 'r').read())
Ids = [d['Id'] for d in jsonout]
print Ids
```

For me, it prints `[u'123', u'456']`

And oh, I should add that unlike I do, you should consider also closing the file.